# Conditional regex to retrieve text

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm new to regex and what I wanna do is that to parse my input as explained below using javascript:

There are 3 types of inputs that I might get:

```
someEmail@domain.com;anotherEmail@domain.com;
```

and

```
some name<someEmail@domain.com>;another name<anotherEmail@domain.com>;
```

or it might be like

```
someEmail@domain.com;another name<anotherEmail@domain.com>;
```

what I'm trying to do is separate the whole input by ; which will give me an array of emails, then check if each of those array items:

1. has < and > then retrieve the text between < and > as value.
2. doesn't have < and > then take the whole text as value.

I'm already trying to learn regex. If anyone gives me the regex, I would appreciate if it comes with an explanation so I can understand and learn.

Cheers

Comment: Don't try to write the "perfect" regex to match an email address, it's a waste of time. All you need is to exclude `<`, `@`, `;` and spaces before the arobase and `>`, `;`, and spaces after. Use https://regex101.com/ to make your attempts.

Comment: @Reeno It's not even worth to post here since I'm new at it. I will try that regex101.com to understand it.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Thank you, I will look into that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this as a starter - avoid the complicated regex - it's not required if your inputs are in the form stated:

```js
str = 'someEmail@domain.com;another name<anotherEmail@domain.com>;someEmail@domain.com;anotherEmail@domain.com;some name<someEmail@domain.com>;another name<anotherEmail@domain.com>;test@test.com';
var splits = str.split(';');
for (var i = 0; i < splits.length; i++) {
  if (splits[i].indexOf('<') == -1) {
    $('#output').append(splits[i] + '<br>');
  } else {
    var address = splits[i].match(/<(.*?)>/)[1];
    $('#output').append(address + '<br>');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='output'></div>
```

Comment: I agree with your point about not using the complex regex, thanks for the code although I could get it myself if I wanted to go non regex, but your hybrid way of getting it much cleaner than that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Splitting is not a bad idea. You can even go further and avoid regular expressions altogether as mentioned in another answer, but since you specifically asked about them:

You could then check each entry in your array with a regular expression like

```
/^([^<]+);/
```

which will match anything that consists only of characters that are not `<` followed by a `;` and

```
/^.*<(.*)>;/
```

which will match anything of the second form your entries may have.

You can combine these into a single regular expression using `|`, but I suggest you simply test twice to avoid having to deal with too many capturing groups. You can even avoid the splitting part by using the `g`lobal modifier, but again, it would make matters a lot more complicated, especially if you're new to regular expressions.

Please note that these examples will match a lot more than email addresses, but checking if they are actually valid is not easy. If you want to look into it, there are plenty of questions on SO about it.

Comment: Thank you for your awesome reply. I will give it a try and I'm pretty sure I will learn a bunch from it. Thanks. voted up